# if first space is 2 space, make it 1 in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

i have a text file and in some lines the first space from left is 2 space long and i want it to be 1 space long. whats the script for this in bash?

```
123  2  5//problem
1 2  5
1 2  5
1  32  5//problem
```

what i want

```
123 2  5
1 2  5
1 2  5
1 32  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]*[ ]\)[ ]*/\1/' input
```

Starting from the left

```
^
```

match and capture non-space characters and a space

```
\([^ ][^ ]*[ ]\)
```

and any number of additional spaces:

```
[ ]*   # remove the star if you only care about exactly 2 spaces
```

and replace these with the captured part:

```
 \1
```

Comment: will the first one look for the first space with length 2 or just look at the first space from left and change it if its length is 2?

Comment: Note to OS X users (at least as of 10.8): As a simpler alternative, you can use the following: `sed -E 's/^([^ ]+ )[ ]+/\1/' input`. Note the `-E` to turn on extended regexes, which (a) adds support for the `+` quantifier (among other features) and (b) removes the need for escaping the parentheses. (Using `+` as the quantifier for the final space has the added advantage that only *multi*-space sequences trigger a match, whereas the original is also triggered by a single space, too (in which case the replacement performed is essentially a no-op).)

Answer (score 3):

`tr` way:

```
cat test.txt | tr -s ' '
```

Comment: Just to clarify: this will fold *all* spans of two or more spaces into a single space each.

Comment: @mklement: Right, this doesn't solve the problem that was asked.

Comment: Yes, I see now. I didn't realize we still need to keep two spaces between #2 and #3 columns. If this is the case, I'd go with `cat-while` approach from another answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I realized that David's answer was almost right.*

You can use sed.

```
cat x | sed -e 's/ \+/ /'
```

This replaces the first occurrence of one or more spaces with a single space.

But you can do it purely in bash as well:

```
cat x | while read a b ; do echo "$a" "$b" ; done
```

This splits each line at the first word, and echos back the first word and the rest of the line. The result is that there is only one space between the first word and the rest of the line.

Comment: Note to OS X users (at least as of 10.8): Use the following sed command instead (**note: had to use `º` in lieu of spaces, because - ironically - SO apparently folds multiple spaces into one in comments**): `cat x | sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)ºº/\1º/'`. Note the `-E` to turn on extended regexes, which (a) adds support for the `+` quantifier (among other features) and (b) removes the need for escaping the parentheses and `+`.